# how to handle back to back characters in postfix notation

Tags: java, stack, postfix-notation

how do you account for two characters back to back while using a stack and postfix notation?  I have converted my postfix equation to a string and then trying to account if it is a character or a number and putting the numbers into a stack. My first equation runs fine but due to two characters being back to back in my second one it doesn't run.  When I run into the second it doesn't have two numbers to use the postfix notation because of not having a number to read after pushing the last one into the stack. Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;
import java.util.Queue;

public class postFixCalc extends Program2Test{
    static Program2Test<Integer> calcStack = new Program2Test<>();

    private static int calc1(String exp) {
        Stack<Integer> calc1Stack = new Stack<>();

        try {
        for(int i = 0; i<exp.length(); i++) {
            char c = exp.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isDigit(c))
                calc1Stack.push(c-'0');
            else {
                int val1 = 0;
                int val2= 0;
                if(!calc1Stack.isEmpty()) {
                val1= calc1Stack.pop();
                val2= calc1Stack.pop();}

                switch(c){
                    case '+':
                        calc1Stack.push(val2+val1);
                        break;

                    case '-':
                        calc1Stack.push(val2-val1);
                        break;

                    case '/':
                        calc1Stack.push(val2/val1);
                        break;

                    case '*':
                        calc1Stack.push(val2*val1);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        }
        catch(EmptyStackException e) {
            System.out.println("Your stack is empty");      }
        return calc1Stack.pop();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String exp = "12+4*5-";     
        System.out.println("Your Answer is: " + calc1(exp));
        System.out.println("");
        String exp2 = "12*4*1-/53+";
        System.out.println("Your answer is: " + calc1(exp2));



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of postfix notation, your expression `exp2` is actually invalid. You evaluate postfix expressions by evaluating the operations from left to right. So, to calculate the expression `12*4*1-/53+` by hand, we do the following:

Starting at the left, we scan the expression until we find the first operator, *. Then we evaluate the two immediate previous operands, 1 and 2, with the * operator and replace those 3 input values with the output, yielding 24*1-/53+. Now repeat the process.

We scan from the left and find the operator *. We evaluate it on the previous two operands, 2 and 4, and again replace the inputs with the output, yielding 81-/53. Repeat.

This time, we get to the operator -. We evaluate it on the previous two operands, 8 and 1, and replace the inputs with the output, yielding. 7/53+. Repeat.

We scan to find a / operator. But wait! There is only one operand to the left of the operator. This isn't allowed, meaning your input is invalid.

Comment: That's what I thought but it was provided to me this way as needing for an answer.  So with that being the understanding would I just throw an exception and catch it with an invalid postfix notation?

Comment: I'm assuming this is some sort of an assignment, so you may want to ask your instructor what functionality he/she desires. If that's not an option, I would just throw an invalid input exception when you detect inputs like these.